# fetching single Record from database using asp.net and jquery ajax but getting error undefined

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am writing code to fetch a single record from a database and display it in a modal dialog using ASP.Net and jQuery AJAX. I retrieve data in JSON format successfully but when I want to display it in the form fields it shows error undefined.

When I `alert` it, it shows data using `data.d` but when I try to display individual fields it's not showing:

```js
    $(function () {
        $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_linkedit_0').click(function () {

            var pid = 2;
            alert(pid);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'WebServiceGetProductDetails.asmx/getProductDetails',
               // contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                //  data: JSON.stringify({id:pid }),
                data:{id:pid},
                method: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {


                    var data1 = JSON.stringify(data);
                    alert(data1);


                    //$('#lblname').val(data.d.empname);
                    //$('#lbldept').val(data.d.dept);
                    //$('#lblsalary').val(data.d.salary);

                },
                error: function (err) {
                    alert(err);
                }


            });
        });

    });
```

it returns data  as ---

{"pid":2,"bid":1,"modalname":"Superb RO","tname":"RO+UV+UF","color":"White","capacity":"6.5L","etype":"Electrical and Storage","powreq":"External AC / DC Adaptor 230 V AC / 24 V DC, 2.5 A","powcon":"35W","pdetail":"Power Supply 2.5 Amps + Power Cord (Nec), Bracket for Adaptor (Nector), Plumbing Kit Assembly - AG Superb RO / GR -RO, Diverter Valve Assembly with Connector - PX","price":0,"qty":5,"pimg":"~/ProductsImg/RO01.jpeg","brand":"Aquagaurd"}

now I want to show each value separately in paragraph

Comment: We need to see your HTML and also the JSON being returned. If you're trying to set the value of `input` fields you need to use the `val()` method

Comment: Can you post a json data line?